# MKMapViewDelegate is called but Pin does not drop as I set

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpinannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I try to make a pin annotation to drop in MapView . But it doesn't .

The view controller has one table view  and I plug mapView into the header.

```
DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 self.title = @"Nearby";

  //coord is CLLocationCoordinate2D which is instance variable 

 ItemMapPoint *itemMapPoint = [[SquakItemMapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord title:@"Test"];
[mapView addAnnotation:itemMapPoint];


MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 500, 500);
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
//the delegate is not set here but I set it in Interface Builder

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = mapView;

}
/this is delegate method to set Pin to drop 
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id     <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
  MKPinAnnotationView *annoView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
 initWithAnnotation:annotation
 reuseIdentifier:@"current"];  


annoView.animatesDrop = YES;
annoView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
return annoView;
}
```

Pin is green as I set in the delegate but Pin does not drop when the screen load. I tried to change the code to ViewDidAppear() also but it still does not work.

Please help .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with annotations yet, but maybe try adding it after the map has finished loading, using the delegate function mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:

Answer (score 0):

Two things-

1. Make sure ur `ItemMapPoint` and `SquakItemMapPoint` implement the needed protocols.
2. Try adding the `mapView` i.e. `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = mapView;` before u add   annotation(s) i.e. `[mapView addAnnotation:itemMapPoint];`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is still does not work for me. SquakItemMappoint is already conform to MKAnnotation protocol. And I try to set self.tableView.tableHeaderView = mapView first but still no luck .

Comment: is there any compiler warning u getting?

Comment: No, i didn't get any . But this view controller is got called when I click on my tableviewcell.